# How to use a separate container service with each containerised celery worker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, celery

I am using `docker-compose` to run multiple celery workers and struggling to make workers use this `zeta0/alpine-tor` rotating proxy pool image the way I want.

Currently my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: .
              target: /app
        links:
            - rabbit
            - tor
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
            - tor
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
           - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=myuser
           - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypassword
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"
    tor:
        hostname: tor
        image: zeta0/alpine-tor
        environment:
            - tors=25
            - privoxy=1
            - new_circuit_period=10
        ports:
            - "8118:8118"
            - "2090:2090"
```

And then I run: `docker-compose up --scale worker=5`.

The problem is that all workers are using the same tor service. I want to have a separate alpine-tor service for every worker. Is this possible to do with `docker-compose`? If so, what should I change to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the `worker` as 5 different docker-compose services(but all  using the same `worker` image), and also running the `tor` service as 5 different docker-compose services(again, using the same `tor` image).

For each of the 5 `worker` services, you could pass in an environment variable indicating which `tor` service you want the worker to communicate with. Then in your worker, you can use this environment variable in the `tor` URL.

So your docker-compose.yml would look like this(some config removed for brevity):

```
version: '3'
services:
    worker_1:
        environment:
            - TOR_SERVICE=tor_1
        ...
    worker_2:
        environment:
            - TOR_SERVICE=tor_2
        ...
    worker_3:
        environment:
            - TOR_SERVICE=tor_3
        ...
    worker_4:
        environment:
            - TOR_SERVICE=tor_4
        ...
    worker_5:
        environment:
            - TOR_SERVICE=tor_5
        ...
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
           - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=myuser
           - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypassword
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"
    tor_1:
        ...
    tor_2:
        ...
    tor_3:
        ...
    tor_4:
        ...
    tor_5:
        ...
```

Comment: How exactly do I use `TOR_SERVICE` variable in worker? I used to call requests via Tor proxy like this `tor:8118`. Now it is not working..

Comment: What is your backend TOR service written in? Python? If so, you can access it with `tor_url = os.environ['TOR_SERVICE'] + ':8118'`. Then use the `tor_url` variable to connect to the TOR service